# JavaFX coordinates confusion

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am really confused by different concepts of coordinates in JavaFX.

As far as I know, there are 3 types of coordinates:

- getBoundsInLocal
- getBoundsInParent
- localToScene

Given a Node "node", contained by a Group "group", recursively contained by a Scene "scene", what are the coordinates "node" to "group" and "node" to "scene"? Which method should I use to set and modify coordinates?

One more question, for object like Polygon, when create a polygon its required to input coordinates. What coordinates should I input? The coordinates at this time belong to which hierarchy?

Sorry for asking this simple question but I spent nearly one day searching JavaFX docs and got no answer. I need more explanation. Is there any document introduce these concept? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in the [API docs for the Node class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html). Basically:

- `boundsInLocal` are a Node's bounds in its own coordinate space (and before transformations like scale and rotate are applied).
- `boundsInParent` are a Node's bounds in its Parent's coordinate space (and after transformations are applied).
- `localToScene` and `localToScreen` are methods that can give you the bounds of the Node in the Scene's or Screen's coordinate space.

Comment: Thanks :D. I found something surprising using scene builder in AnchorPane. Suppose a Pane belong to an AnchorPane. When compute the Pane's LayoutX it's from left to right. However the LayoutY is computed from top to bottom. Why this happens? Does this always or just for certain panes? How could find it out using code?

Comment: Screen coordinates always have Y going from top (0) to bottom (positive). You might also want to take a look at ScenicView. It lets you inspect your GUI like Scene Builder, but while your app is running:  http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/

Answer (score 2):

The [Node documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) describes the differences. And you should take a look at [jewelsea's demo](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1441960), it helps a lot with understanding the layout bounds in JavaFX.

The Polygon is a [Shape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html). You add the coordinates locally, i. e. 0/0 is the coordinate 0/0 inside the Shape. The shape itself can be placed on the scene by using the [setLayoutX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setLayoutX-double-) (and Y) and [setTranslateX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setTranslateX-double-) (and Y) methods.

Comment: Very nice example! Thanks:D